QGIS 3.28 - Point cluster symbology sum attribute
I'm with some trouble to label this cluster map and need help showing the sum of the 'count' attribute. I'm using this expression aggregate( @layer_name,'sum',"count",filter:=intersects($geometry,geometry(@parent), but it keeps returning the label "0".
Does anyone know if there's a simple way to do this?
I'm used to work more with ArcGIS Pro and my doubt is way easier to solve there, and I didn't found similar solutions at QGIS.



Hi there, it's not entirely clear from your question what you expect the output to look like. Can you please show us a clear example of what you expect as a result of this operation?
